# How to reset admin password for Perfino?

Tags: perfino

Question says it all - how can I reset the admin password for a Perfino install ?  I have root access to the box Perfino is installed on.

(I could not find help on the Perfino site - which pointed me here to ask questions !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no utility to reset passwords if you do not have admin access to the perfino UI.

However, you can modify the "USER" table in the database manually. I would recommend to install perfino on a different machine and set up an admin user with the desired password. Then you can copy the "CONTENT" column of the admin user (an XML document that contains the configuration of the user including the password hash) and update the admin user on the original machine with that value.

If you use the bundled H2 database then edit `perfino.properties` and ensure that the startH2Console property is set like this:

```
startH2Console=true
```

Then start perfino and open a browser at http://localhost:8082 and click on "Connect" (no password required). In the SQL box enter "SELECT * from USER". You can then copy or edit the "CONTENT" column.

Comment: (I know StackOverflow frowns on these kinds of messages- But THANK YOU).